# This code is not calculating things right, any ideas why?

Tags: c, cs50

Well, suppose that a cashier owes a customer some change and in that cashier’s drawer are quarters (25¢), dimes (10¢), nickels (5¢), and pennies (1¢). The problem to be solved is to decide which coins and how many of each to hand to the customer

if some customer is owed 41¢, the biggest first  bite that can be taken is 25¢
41 - 25 = 16
 another 25¢ bite would be too big
cashier would move on to a bite of size 10¢, leaving him or her with a 6¢ problem
 At that point the cashier calls for one 5¢ bite followed by one 1¢ bite

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    float f = get_float("Enter Cash: ");

    int q;
    int d;
    int n;
    int p;

    float quarter = 0.25;
    float dimes = 0.10;
    float nickels = 0.05;
    float pennies = 0.01;

    while ( f != 0)
    {

        if (f >= quarter){

            f = f - quarter;
            q = q + 1;
        } else if (f >= dimes && f < quarter) {

            f = f - dimes;
            d = d + 1;
        } else if (f >= nickels && f < dimes) {

            f = f - nickels;
            n = n + 1;        
        } else {
            f = f - pennies;
            p = p + 1;
        }
        printf ("Quarter: %d \n Dimes %d \n Nickels %d \n Pennies %d \n", q, 
        d, n, p);
    }
}
```

```
$ ./cash
Enter Cash: 6
Quarter: 32768 
 Dimes -1230737968 
 Nickels 0 
 Pennies 4205168 
Quarter: 32769 
 Dimes -1230737968 
 Nickels 0 
 Pennies 4205168 
Quarter: 32770 
 Dimes -1230737968 
 Nickels 0 
 Pennies 4205168 
Quarter: 32771 
 Dimes -1230737968 
 Nickels 0 
 Pennies 4205168 
Quarter: 32772
```

Comment: You do not initialize the variables! So `int q;` ==> `int q = 0;`

Comment: Also, don't use double/float for monetary operations.

Comment: BTW: Do the calculation in integer instead of float

Comment: You should enable warnings in your compiler. It should tell you that you are using variables without initialization. And if you get warnings, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize your variables

```
int q = 0;
int d = 0;
int n = 0;
int p = 0;
```

otherwise they have unpredictable values

Comment: Thank you guys, but even after initializing them still dosn't work
    int q = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int p = 0;

i'm reaciving command not found when i enter any number